# Fortran Editor in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, gcc, fortran, gfortran

I want to make a Fortran editor in iPhone. User can code with Fortran in an iOS app and are also able to run that code on iPhone.

Can anyone guide me with correct approach?

I had a look to the gFortran, but its not available for ARM architecture.

Thankyou..

Comment: Apple doesn't allow compilers/interpreters on iOS devices

Comment: Thank you for providing a new definition for "hell"

Comment: If you just want to play around with FORTRAN on your iOS device then there is CodeToGo which supports many languages including FORTRAN: http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/codetogo/id382677229?mt=8

Answer (score 2):

Apple doesn't allow for compilers or interpreters on the iPhone, but there technically isn't any reason you can't setup a server based compiler, that also allows users to run their compiled apps. In fact, there are multiple sites that already do just this, but it wouldnt be a good idea to write an app that points to their site or uses their services; you would need to setup your own service.

Not insurmountable, but I would move onto other app ideas.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. But there are application that allows user to code with BASIC language in iPhone. Have a look to these applications: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/basic!/id362411238?mt=8, http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hand-basic-cbm-flavor/id394924289?mt=8

Comment: Apparently Apple has changed some of the rules surrounding rejections from the App Store, but I would still be wary about getting a full-on compiler past them. You'll need to look into Apple's terms of service, which can be found on the Apple Developer website. As for a Fortran compiler that would run on the iPhone; you would likely need to roll your own--Sources: [New Era?](http://www.imore.com/2010/09/17/google-voice-app-basic-interpreter-hit-app-store-era-begins/) and [FCC](http://www.imore.com/2009/07/31/fcc-investigating-google-voice-rejection-apples-itunes-app-store-atts-involvement/)

Comment: Here's some additional information regarding an ARM compatible Fortran compiler: [Perpetual Notion](http://perpetual-notion.blogspot.com/2009/11/simple-cross-fortran-compiler-for-arm.html) -- Well, sorta. It actually gets around the issue by converting Fortran to C then compiling, but it's all I can find.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to setup a full ARM based virtual machine with gcc (including gfortran) and compile there?

Answer (score 1):

Given Apple's snarly attitude about language interpreters running under iOS you're better off coding this as service that runs on a remote server, maybe with the editing part on the phone or tablet.

Comment: Hi Kyle, Thanks for your response. But there are application that allows user to code with BASIC language in iPhone. Have a look to these applications: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/basic!/id362411238?mt=8, http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hand-basic-cbm-flavor/id394924289?mt=8

Comment: @Musti: this *probably* uses the same approach as CodeToGo - the interpreter is not actually resident on the iOS device ?

Answer (score 0):

Updating this old thread for the sake of current and future searches:

Apple has changed their attitude over the past year or so. There are currently many interpreters available for iOS, including for Lua (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iluabox/id398073834?mt=8) and several for Python (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/python-2.7-for-ios/id485729872?mt=8, http://itunes.com/apps/pythonmath).

One significant remaining restriction is that these apps may not load scripts from outside the app, for example, from Dropbox or iTunes file sharing. (This is part of Apple's efforts -- along with code signing and 100% app review -- to minimize malware.) Such apps are allowed to have an editor that allows the user to copy and paste code into the editor from outside the app.

As far as I know, there aren't any apps for compiled languages such as FORTRAN.

Meanwhile, FORTRAN compiler is available for iOS only as a jailbroken application.

[Disclaimer: I am the author of Python Math. Apple removed it from the store for a short time until I removed iTunes file sharing and "Open In..." capability. I then added a script editor.]